# How to set a string to perform a function or command

Tags: c

I kind of have a basic question for you because it's driving me crazy. How do I go about writing my functions to specific strings? Like, if I was creating a while loop and wanted the program to end, how would I write it so that the program itself ends when I type in "end" when it asks for input?

EDIT: Alright, so I figured out pretty easily how to end my function by typing "end", but now for some reason depending on how many sentences I write, my program keeps repeating itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
int i;
char buf[10];
printf("Command? ");
scanf("%s", buf);

while(buf != "end")
{
    if(strcmp(buf, "end")== 0){
        break;
    }

    switch( buf[i] ){
    //Where the cases will inevitably go
    default:
    puts("I'm sorry, but that's not a command.\n");
    break;
    }
    printf("Command? ");
    scanf("%s", buf);
}
puts("End of Program.");
getch();
}
```

Comment: Compare the string to "end" and break out of the loop or call `exit`?

Comment: Try `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm extremely new, can you provide an example? I know strcmp compares two strings but how does that exactly relate?

Comment: Your first step is getting input, then you want to compare that input to expected values (eg. "end"), then you want to act accordingly.  Have you done step 1 and gotten user input yet (maybe using `scanf` or `gets`?

Comment: OH! I know exactly what you mean now! Yes I used scanf in order to receive input, but just couldn't figure out the concept of strcmp, which now seems incredibly useful. What was happening is that my program wasn't recognizing my input commands so I realize what you mean by comparing my input to my "end" value and if so then close the program. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
char *myInputString = NULL;
while (1) {
    /* read in myInputString from user input, and test... */
    if (strcmp(myInputString, "foo") == 0)
        break;
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```